# How to integrate Astra sdk with visual studio 2013 C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, integration, orbbec

I'm very new to C#. So i'm asked to code a simple swipe gesture using Orbbec Astra and visual studio 2013 using c#. I've downloaded the astra sdk file and found some documentations on how to get started like initiatilization and terminating astra. 
The problem now is it's in C++ and i want it in C#
[image]

I downloaded the astra sdk for visual studio here:
https://orbbec3d.com/develop/

*64 bit*
The documentations that i was referring to is in 
\AstraSDK-v2.0.12-b48cd2945b-20180924T184549Z-vs2013-win64 (1)\AstraSDK-v2.0.12-b48cd2945b-20180924T184549Z-vs2013-win64\docs\html-en

This is the device: Orbbec Astra Pro
[image]

I'm stucked , i don't know where to start. I was told that i have to intergrate the astra sdk visual studio 2013 in C#.I can't find resources online, especially for C#. Also, i have installed orbbec Astra into my computer. Now i just have to integrate astra sdk to visual studio 2013 using c#.Please help me ;(

Comment: On https://orbbec3d.com/develop/ it claims there's already a C#/.NET wrapper. I would be looking for examples that use that rather than the C++ code. If there aren't such examples in an obvious place, you may want to ask Orbbec support for them directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you consult their dev page: https://orbbec3d.com/develop/ 
I believe the C# documententation/drivers/etc is here under Unity, https://orbbec3d.com/develop/#unity
Since unity uses C# language.